# Replace multiple occurrences of a dynamic string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I will illustrate code what I'm doing:

I have data that has strings such as:

```
[[-55-]], [[-75-]]
```

Which I use to do something like:

```
$var = 'hi my name is [[-55-]] and I think yoda looks like a bald green [[-75-]].';
$var = str_replace('[[-', '<img src="/', $var);
$var = str_replace('-]], '">', $var);
```

What I would like to do is end up with the image output something like:

```
<a href="/stuff/55/"><img src="/55.png"></a>
```

The problem is, that takes more than a simple str_replace and I am beyond terrible at regex.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all separated by the same delimeter?  If so, read the "[[-55-]], [[-75-]]" into a $string then use, explode(",", $string) and use the $array[55], $array[75] as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$var = 'hi my name is [[-55-]] and I think yoda looks like a bald green [[-75-]].';
$result = preg_replace('/\[\[-(\d+)-\]\]/', '<a href="/stuff/\1/"><img src="/\1.png"></a>', $var);
```

Comment: Thanks for writing my answer for me. ;) Only difference is that the RegEx should be: `/\[\[-(\d+?)-\]\]/`.